# MySQL Table inside Table or Alternative

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails

A system I am making has Table Users, wherein each user has his/her own userid.

Each user needs to belong to multiple groups.

Each group can have multiple users.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should learn a bit more about relational databases before starting your project (at least about 1-n / 0-n / n-n relashionships and foreign keys), it'll make you save time in the end ;)

Comment: Can you be more constructive and help @AKRamkumar out with some resources to learn about such wonderful sugesstions?

Comment: Use a third table to connect USER and GROUP. So say.. Group 1 have multiple user. The 3rd table would have lots of records with a user field and a group field with value 'Group 1'. You can do the same with Users for the third table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three tables:

USER:
  - UserID
  - UserName

GROUP:
  - Group_ID
  - Group_Name
  - Group_Privelages

GROUP_USER:
  - Group_id
  - User_id

GROUP_USER would hold the relations of User to group - one user could be in many groups, or one, or none.

Comment: +1: But make the group_id and user_id columns in GROUP_USER to be the primary key to stop duplicates.

Comment: :-) I was debating whether to go that far in the example, valid point though. Same applies for user_id in USER and group_id in GROUP

Answer (score 1):

Use many-to-many association. Maybe this will help: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php